# Return a dynamically allocated array? (C)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

Consider the given 2d array allocation:

```
int (*some)[10] = malloc(sizeof(int[10][10]));
```

This allocates a 10 x 10 2d array. Apparently its type is `int (*)[10]`. I want to write a function `initialize()` that will allocate it, initialize it and then return a pointer to the array, so that the construction `some[i][j]` would be usable in other functions which can pass a pointer to the array it onto each other.

What should the prototype, specifically the return type of `initialize()` be?

Comment: `(*some)[10]` is pointer to array of 10 elements not pointer to pointer what you think.

Comment: I recommend that you create a type-alias for complex types like this. Will make it much easier to use.

Comment: It didn't let me write `int (*)[] initialize()` as a function type.

Comment: because it must be `int (*initialize(void))[10]{}` in the same way you have to do `int (*some)[10] =...`

Comment: If you don't like the syntax, you could declare a type alias such as `typedef int a10int[10];`, then declare the function as `a10int *function(void);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int (*initialize(void))[10] { ... }
```

`initialize` is a function, which takes no parameters and returns a pointer to an array of `10` `int`.

You should use a `typedef` for that.

Answer (score 0):

allocates the table of `nrow` pointers to (allocated) int array of `size` elements

```
void *allocate_rows(int *(*ptr)[size], size_t nrows)
{
    int (*tmpptr)[size] = *ptr;

    *ptr = malloc(nrows * sizeof(*ptr));

    if(*ptr)
    {
        while(nrows--)
        {
            tmpptr = malloc(sizeof(*tmpptr));
            if(!tmpptr)
            {
                /* malloc failed do something */
            }
            else 
            {
                tmpptr++;
            }
        }
    return *ptr;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I understand what's going on in that parameter list.

Answer (score 0):

In 
`int (*some)[10] = malloc(sizeof *some);`, `some` is a "pointer to an array of 10 int`.

If you want `other` to be a function returning a pointer to an array of of 10 int, you can start with `int (*some)[10];` and replace `some` with what a call to a such function would look like to get your declaration.

`int (*some)[10];` => `int (*other(argument1,argument2))[10];`

That's how it worked in pre-standardized C. Since standardized C has prototypes, you'd also replace the argument identifier list with a parameter type list, e.g.:

```
int (*other(int argument1, double argument2))[10];
```

The cdecl program or the [cdecl website can help you verify the result](https://cdecl.org/?q=int%20%28*other%28int%20%2C%20double%20%29%29%5B10%5D%3B):

```
$ echo 'explain   int (*other(int,double))[10]'|cdecl
  declare other as function (int, double) returning pointer to array 10 of int
```

Most people find `typedef`s more readable:

```
typedef int (*pointer_to_an_array_of_10_int)[10];
pointer_to_an_array_of_10_int other(int, double);

//to verify it's a compatible declaration 
int (*other(int , double ))[10];
```